# Can I connect a flask app to a database using MySQLdb-python vertica_python?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to connect a Flask app to a database using MySQLdb-python and vertica_python? It seems that the recommended Flask library for accessing databases is Flask-SQLAlchemy.  I have an app that connects to MySQL and Vertica databases, and have written a GUI wrapper for it in Flask using flask-wtforms, but am just getting an error when I try to test a Vertica or MySQL connection through the flask app. Is there a reason that I cannot use the prior libraries that I was using within my app?

Comment: of coarse its possible ... you can do all the raw sql queries you want just like normal ...

Comment: Can we get some code please? And a stack trace for the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I was having difficulties debugging because of the opacity of the error, but ran it with `app.run(debug=True)`, and managed to troubleshoot my problem.